# Rails Custom Error Pages with Custom Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, routes

I'm following this tutorial: http://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails

However, in my routes file, I have two custom routes:

```
get '/blog',        to: 'blog_posts#index', as: :blog
get '/:id',         to: 'blog_posts#show', as: :show_blog_post
```

When I go to a page that doesn't exist, it isn't redirecting to the error pages. Instead, it's giving me `Completed 404 Not Found. Error during failsafe response: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

The custom routes are somehow not making the error pages work. When I remove the custom routes, everything works fine.

How do I get my error pages to work with this? I would've thought that anything returning a 404 would be redirect to the `ErrorsController`, but that isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

`get '/:id',         to: 'blog_posts#show', as: :show_blog_post`

route seems to be picking up your custom error handling. If a user goes to

`/404`

the `blog_posts#show` gets called with the parameter `id = 404`, and I'm guessing it's trying to look up a blog post with an id of 404 which results in `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

What you can do is place your error rules at the top, before `/:id`, since routes get matched in the order that they're listed, but I'd just recommend not using something like `/:id` since it can accidentally pick things up, like what we're dealing with. Scope the route with something descriptive like `/posts/:id`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Adib. That worked. Just had to move the error routes up top.